# how to do broadcast in SparkR 2.2

Tags: apache-spark, broadcast, sparkr

I find no information for doing broadcast in SparkR 2.2. The syntax
broadcast(sc, object) is for the old versions.

Can anyone provide some sample code for this? along with necessary libraries.

Thanks

Comment: Answer not helpful?

Answer (score 1):

`broadcast()` in SparkR will be available from Spark 2.3, according to [this pull request](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/17965/files).

In Spark 2.2, you should use [`hint()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/R/hint.html); according to the above pull request (scroll down), `broadcast(x)` in Spark 2.3 will be equivalent to `hint(x, "broadcast")`.

Comment: I read the relevant docs over and over and do not get it. are we talking about the same broadcast as https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-broadcast.html? It has nothing to do with data frame.

Comment: apparently, all global variables are automatically broadcasted. I withdraw this post. Thanks for the response